# Flask Security Too Mysql connection problem

Tags: mysql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-security

I'm using Flask Security Too (https://flask-security-too.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) to authenticate users on a test server. I followed the instructions in the documentations to get it up and running. It all works perfect, however for some reason the application is losing the connection to the MySQL server and starts returning an Internal Server Error. In Sentry I see the following error message:

(sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError) Can't reconnect until invalid transaction is rolled back
[SQL: SELECT anon_1.user_id AS anon_1_user_id, anon_1.user_email AS anon_1_user_email, anon_1.user_first_name AS anon_1_user_first_name, anon_1.user_last_name AS anon_1_user_last_name, anon_1.user_password AS anon_1_user_password, anon_1.user_last_login_at AS anon_1_user_last_login_at, anon_1.user_current_login_at AS anon_1_user_current_login_at, anon_1.user_last_login_ip AS anon_1_user_last_login_ip, anon_1.use...

This error usually appears when the site has not been accessed for several hours during night. Restarting the Flask app solves the problem.

I tried changing the SqlAlchemy options, without success. Since I'm using a MySQL database on a dedicated server I also tried using a local MySQL database, I'm having the same issue here.

I would like to solve this issue before spending more time on integrating this into my website.

Does anyone know what can cause this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this (and there have been bugs) when using psycopg2 - where a PRIOR error (such as select on a column with an incompatible type - causes the connection to permanently be unusable. From my testing - there wasn't an obvious way to even know this had happened until the query that throws this error - since it was a coding error - I fixed a few bugs in that area. Note that was with psycopg2 - which I don't think you are using.
I would look at logs or turn on complete mysql query logging to look at what might be querying it during the evening.

Another thought - which I don't think would cause THIS error - is that many DBs drop connections after some period of time out. Make sure you are using Flask-SQLAlchemy 2.4.0 or greater and put in the config:
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_ENGINE_OPTIONS"] = {"pool_pre_ping": True}

which will make sure the connection is valid PRIOR to returning the connection to be used.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. You are right, I'm not using psycopg2 so I guess the issue is not related to it. 

It does look like the MySQL connection is dropped. I am using the latest version of SqlAlchemy and added the pool_pre_ping option. I also tried increasing the timeout in the Mysql settings, but this did not solve the issue unfortunately.

Comment: So then I would enable complete query logging and try to find the query(s) just prior to the one that fails....